# Does present continuous fit in this case

Tags: continuous

don't forget to precise (attention to ......) when you are writing/going to write/write  the address

Is present continuous to express the future ok in this case or will it be better to use present simple or going to . I did not use present simple as it is not a general statement only a one off and did not use  going to as it is not a personal plan but a strong advice given to someone else. 
After thinking of it, may be the best is present simple to express the idea of strong advice

Comment: I don't understand the first part: precise attention to? I'd say : "when writing the address".

Comment: if when writing is the solution when you are writing should be ok

Comment: "when writing" without "you are" is better in my opinion.

Comment: i think you are totally right